# How do I make a url forbidden in apache mod_rewrite, based on the query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

How do I make the following url forbidden in apache;

`main/index.php?site=ing`

I have tried the following;

`RewriteRule ^main/index.php?site=ing - [F]`

but with no luck...

Comment: I added "query string" in both the title and tags so people searching for problems with the query string and mod_rewrite will find this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You [cannot match a query string in the RewriteRule](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString), you have to do

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} site=ing     #Adjust the regexps with anchors
RewriteRule ^main/index.php - [F]
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)site=ing(&|$)
RewriteRule ^main/index\.php$ - [F]
```

Comment: For having `/.well-known/acme-challange/` working: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known/acme-challenge/).* - [F]`

Answer (score 1):

Another non apache solution, would be to do this in the index.php file.

Add something like this to the top of the page.

```
if(isset($_GET['site']) && $_GET['site'] == 'ing'){
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit();
}
```